# CSS selector to match an element without attribute x

Tags: css-selectors, css

I'm working on a CSS file and find the need to style text input boxes, however, I'm running into problems. I need a simple declaration that matches all these elements:

```
<input />
<input type='text' />
<input type='password' />
```

... but doesn't match these ones:

```
<input type='submit' />
<input type='button' />
<input type='image' />
<input type='file' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='radio' />
<input type='reset' />
```

Here's what I would like to do:

```
input[!type], input[type='text'], input[type='password'] {
   /* styles here */
}
```

In the above CSS, notice the first selector is `input[!type]`. What I mean by this is I want to select all input boxes where the type attribute is not specified (because it defaults to text but `input[type='text']` doesn't match it). Unfortunately, there is no such selector in the CSS3 spec that I could find.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: jQuery selectors: use .not(). $("[data-plot-id]").not('[data-bean-id]').css({border: '5px solid red'})

Answer (score 639, accepted):

`:not` selector:

```
input:not([type]), input[type='text'], input[type='password'] {
    /* style here */
}
```

[Support:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) in Internet Explorer 9 and higher

Comment: I have tried for <img alt=" ">   img:not[src=""] { visibility: hidden; width:0; height:0; }  but not working pls help

Comment: Anoops, you definitely should create a new question.

Comment: just need to put attribute name;  img : not( [ src ] )

Answer (score 31):

For a more cross-browser solution you could style **all** inputs the way you want the non-typed, text, and password then another style the overrides that style for radios, checkboxes, etc.

```
input { border:solid 1px red; }

input[type=radio], 
input[type=checkbox], 
input[type=submit], 
input[type=reset], 
input[type=file] 
      { border:none; }
```

- Or -

could whatever part of your code that is generating the non-typed inputs give them a class like `.no-type` or simply not output at all? Additionally this type of selection could be done with jQuery.

Answer (score 11):

Just wanted to add to this, you can have the :not selector in oldIE using selectivizr: http://selectivizr.com/