# hide img tag if src is empty but without javascript/jQuery or css3

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors

I am designing templates in Channel Advisor for eBay store and it doesn't allow `javascript/jQuery`. Also, the `CSS3` doesn't work in various `IE` versions specially the `img[src=]` implementation is broken.

When I use template tags in img like:

```
<img src="{{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL1)}}"/>
```

where {{THUMB(ITEMIMAGEURL1)}} is the image path, if the image is missing and the template is posted to eBay then the end result would be like this:

```
<img src=""/>
```

and this shows a broken image.

Is there a way to hide `<img src=""/>` with HTML or CSS that works in IE7+

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use `[attr=val]` selector

```
img[src=""] {
   display: none;
}
```

The above selector will simply match, if the `src` attribute has no value. This selector is a general one and will match all the `img` tag in the document with an empty `src`, if you want to target specific ones, than use more specific selector like

```
.class_name img[src=""] {
    display: none;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqj7P/)</kbd>

<kbd><s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqj7P/1/)</s></kbd> (Without the above selector, see that red line?)

Alternatively, if you want to reserve the space taken by `img` tag, you might like to use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` as `display: none;` will simply mess your layout where `visibility: hidden;` will reserve the space, it will just hide the `img`

See the difference between `display: none;` and `visibility: hidden;`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqj7P/2/)</kbd> (`visibility: hidden;`, reserves space)

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqj7P/3/)</kbd> (`display: none;`, won't reserve space)

---

> Note: None of the above selectors will REMOVE the `img` tag from the
>   DOM, it will simply hide it from the front end

Comment: For SEO issues leaving `src` empty is not good that's why I personally use `#` as src. The global Seo friendly selector would be `img[src=""], img[src="#"], img:not([src])`

Answer (score 10):

`[attr=value]` selector is CSS2, you should be ok.

```
img[src=""] {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If src attribute is missing altogether:

```
img:not([src]), img[type='src'], img[type='src'] {
display:none !important;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1533485/10634638)