# jQuery: How to find every <a> tags without link/href and replace the href with its text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this scenario that in a page there are some `<a>` tags without any `href` links.

what I'm trying to do is to find those `<a>` tags and get their `text` and create a `href attribute` for them using their `text`.

I have tried this so far but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of
```

My current code:

```js
$(document.body).find("a:not([href])").contents().this.attr('href').this.attr('href').replace('htt://google.com', '');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>An unarmed man was shot in Southwest <a>Atlanta</a>, and <a href='stackoverflow.com'>Panthersville</a> residents want answers.
```

could someone please advice on this issue?

**This is not a CSS question!!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css selector to match an element without attribute x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533444/css-selector-to-match-an-element-without-attribute-x)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, CSS?! Really?

Comment: whoever, marked this question as a duplicate of a totally unrelated question should explain why they feel like that this is a duplicate!!

Comment: You are aware that jQuery's `$("...")` is literally CSS queries, right? If not: that's how jQuery works, it's pretty convenient. Select all your `<a>` without `href` attribute, after that, your question is literally "just do those things, jquery's API is pretty clearly written for that part"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, whether it is CSS or not, this question has nothing to do with CSS and jQuery certainly IS NOT CSS.

Comment: "finding HTML elements without a specific attribute" is 100% a CSS selector question when your framework is jQuery, because that is literally how jQuery was designed to work. So: you find the CSS selector for the thing you need to do, which is `a:not([href])` as per the question this is effectively a duplicate of, and then you ask jQuery to resolve: `$("a:not([href])")`. Now you have all `<a>` without an href attribute. You can even run that in your dev console on *this very page* to see it work.

Comment: jQuery can manipulate the CSS but again it is NOT CSS and the question was not 'how can I do this using CSS' or anything remotely related to CSS.

Comment: In that case you clearly don't understand how jQuery works, because using the right CSS **selector** (_not_ a CSS styling declaration, they are two different things, even though the latter relies on the first) is literally the answer to your question. Which you seem to have realised by accepting the answer that shows the exact same code I gave you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, why are you trying to force your opinion on others? does it make you feel good about yourself?!? I said it 3 times and I will say  it again for the last time... jQuery is jQuery and CSS is CSS. Totally different things. THIS question was not about CSS which makes your argument absolutely useless and irrelevant.

Comment: mostly because if you ask about jQuery, it helps to know how it works. jQuery and CSS cannot be separated because jQuery, as per its official documentation, **relies on CSS selectors**. But don't take my word for it, [head on over to the official documentation yourself](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) and (re)familiarise yourself with jQuery. It's fine to not know how a framework works, but it's kind of silly to stay angry at someone who is telling you how it actually works.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans listen to your own advice. It's fine to not know how a framework works but its kinda silly to keep trying to force your opinion on others when you and everybody else know that you were/are wrong!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('a:not([href])').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).text())
})
```

```js
$('a:not([href])').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>An unarmed man was shot in Southwest <a>Atlanta</a>, and <a href='stackoverflow.com'>Panthersville</a> residents want answers.
<p>An unarmed man was shot in Southwest <a>Chicago</a>, and <a href='stackoverflow.com'>Panthersville</a> residents want answers.
```

This iterates through all anchors without an href attribute and creates the attribute using the anchor's text.