# Why does querySelectorAll on text type miss inputs with implicit text type?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I have a plain `<input>` element.

I would expect `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')` to retrieve (at least) that input, since [the default input type is `text`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).

But `querySelectorAll` does not return that input unless I explicitly set `type="text"`.

I have two questions:

1. Why does querySelectorAll ignore the input with an implicit `type="text"`?
2. Is there a query to target an input whose implicit type is `text` that excludes all inputs whose types are not `text`?

Here is an example document illustrating the question:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

output.innerText = 'input[type="text"] - ' + textInputs.length + ' elements';

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

output.innerText += '\ninput - ' + inputs.length + ' elements';

output.innerText += '\n\nFirst input type: ' + inputs[0].type;
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <input type="text">
  <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript output in my browser (Chrome):

```
input[type="text"] - 1 elements
input - 2 elements

First input type: text
```

Comment: Because it's an attribute equals selector. If the attribute doesn't exist, it doesn't equal `"text"`.

Comment: @Nope yeah. To be fair, the type _is_ `text` by default... Seems like this is just an eccentricity of `querySelectorAll` which I wasn't expecting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533444/css-selector-to-match-an-element-without-attribute-x

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type]), input[type=text]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute selectors don't take invalid or missing value defaults into account. They will only match when the attribute has explicitly been specified in the markup.

You can still account for the missing value default using `input:not([type])`, since an `input` element without a `type` attribute is guaranteed, by its missing value default, to be a text input (unless mutated by scripts).

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

var textInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type]), input[type=text]');

output.innerText = 'input[type="text"] - ' + textInputs.length + ' elements';

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

output.innerText += '\ninput - ' + inputs.length + ' elements';

output.innerText += '\n\nFirst input type: ' + inputs[0].type;
```

```css
#output { 
  font-family: monospace; 
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="number">
    <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know of any documentation for this behavior (specifically, not `querySelectorAll` generically), and are you aware of an alternative query which will satisfy the requirement in question part 2?

Comment: @mac9416: Unfortunately this isn't spelled out in either the HTML or Selectors specs. The closest I can find is [§2.4.3 of W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#keywords-and-enumerated-attributes) which describes the missing value default as what's used when the attribute is "missing" or "absent", and [the Selectors spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors) simply describing attribute selectors as matching based on the presence of attributes. You'll have to connect the dots from there.

Comment: @mac9416: Hmm, I didn't notice your suggested edit there. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does querySelectorAll ignore the input with an implicit type="text"?

Since it is implicit, the attribute does not exist on the element, so the attribute selector doesn't match it.

> Is there a query to target an input whose implicit type is text that excludes all inputs whose types are not text?

Match elements with no type attribute at all.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text], input:not([type])").length,
  "matching elements"
);
```

```css
input[type=text],
input:not([type]) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><input></li>
  <li><input type="text"></li>
  <li><input type="number"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some answers:

1. As already mentioned by many, `querySelectorAll` needs the type to be explicit to match it.
2. You may want to use the code in the snippet to "filter" the result of the `querySelectorAll`.

**Third answer:**
*Using `.setAttribute("type", "text")` to explicitly add the attribute on the elements without it*

```js
// Add 'type="text"' on the ones which don't have it
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type])').forEach(function(elm){
  elm.setAttribute("type", "text");
});

// Output
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
document.getElementById('output').innerText += 'input[type="text"] - ' + inputs.length + ' elements';
```

```html
<form><!-- Added other input types -->
  <input>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
  <input type="date">
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
  </script>
</form>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Second answer (others were faster):**
*Adding `input:not([type])` in the `querySelectorAll`*

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"], input:not([type])');

output.innerText += 'input[type="text"] - ' + inputs.length + ' elements';
```

```html
<form><!-- Added other input types -->
  <input>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
  <input type="date">
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
  </script>
</form>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

**First answer (not worth it):**
*Using a loop to check each element returned by the `querySelectorAll`*

```js
// Variables
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var textInputs = [],
  j = 0;

// Loop
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].type == 'text') {
    textInputs[j] = inputs[i];
    j++
  }
}

// Output
output.innerText = 'input[type="text"] - ' + textInputs.length + ' elements';
```

```html
<form><!-- Added other input types -->
  <input>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
  <input type="date">
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
  </script>
</form>
```

Hope it helps.